# image clustering, k means

Tags: image, cluster-analysis

i have input image [my input image](http://ulozto.cz/xJisVPRj/obraz-bmp)

my code is

```
img = imread('obraz.bmp');
img=rgb2gray(img)
imshow(img)

%% normalization 
img = ( img - min(img(:)) ) ./ ( max(img(:)) - min(img(:)) );

img = ~img;
[m n]=size(img)
P = [];
for i=1:m    
    for j=1:n        
        if img(i,j)>=1
            P = [P ; i j];        
        end
    end
end

size(P);
MON=P;     

[IDX,ctrs] = kmeans(MON,3);
clusteredImage = zeros(size(img));
clusteredImage(sub2ind(size(img) , P(:,1) , P(:,2)))=IDX;

imshow(label2rgb(clusteredImage))
```

My output image is [my output image](http://ulozto.cz/x4Cw9QDH/123-png)

My output is not correct, I have to be logically correct output

can anyone help?, I don't understand to clustering image.

Comment: It is not clear what this code is supposed to do, and it isn't clear what language you are writing in. Please edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you say that the output is not correct. It seems fine to me.

See, if you run k-means using the squared Euclidean distance (as you did) the clusters will be biased towards spherical shapes. Unfortunately for you, one of the clusters in the image is not spherical. You can see that each spherical cluster has a unique colour, but the cluster that isn't spherical doesn't.